# Nuxt Static Site 404 Error page not rendering dynamic content correctly

Tags: vue.js, apache, nuxt.js

**Edit**
Ok i managed to solve the error template not being loaded. It was an htaccess issue. If I change the ErrorDocument to be /sub/dirs/error.html (note the missing dist folder) it works correcty. However it still doesnt have the full functionality of the dynamic menu and the autocomplete search bar which I really need to work. Any ideas on that?

Im having some issues with my production ready Nuxt App.
I have the following in my nuxt.config.js

```
target: 'static',
  generate: {
    dir: '../dist',
    fallback: 'error.html'
  },
```

`// The error part is solved, dynamic menus continue to be an issue`

It correctly generates the error.html file on `npm run generate` as expected. However it doesn't use the content in layouts/error.vue and the dynamic menus in the header don't load their data. I'm sure its actually loading error.html as i can manually update the HTML (title,text etc via vscode) and it updates. However if i load the error page directly (example.com/error.html) it actually works as expected with the correct error.vue template being rendered as expected.

Once the 404 is thrown it also tries to load the missing route. My setup is

```
pages
--categories
  --_cat-id
--_page-id
```

If I hit something like example.com/this-page-doesnt-exist it throws a 404 but still loads the page _page-id and runs all the code. That doesnt seem normal, and I don't really want that. I want it to load the error page and the error page only.
Lastly I am using apache/htaccess to handle ErrorDocument. If i remove that it just uses apaches built in 404 which is not an option. Im wondering if there is something in a rewrite rule that may be causing this.

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /sub/dirs/dist/error.html
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sub/dirs/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

How do I get my error page to render correctly as well as the dynamic content from the menus etc to load? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please remove the part of the question that is (no more) relevant to clear the question a bit.

Comment: I think that the answer still might be relevant to people with a similar setup? I spent 2 days trying to figure out all the different moving parts on this one.

Comment: Feel free to post a question and answer it there. Otherwise, leave it as is if you feel like those 2 are heavily connected but update the title to reflect a bit more what is to be achieved at the end of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the Error page not loading at all by updating my htaccess.
New .htaccess - remove the dist from the ErrorDocument.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /sub/dirs/error.html
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /sub/dirs/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit. I have a work around for the dynamic data. It seems that the error page was not being generated completely when you set `target:static`. All the other html generated pages are complete pages but not the error.html one. I couldn't get the asyncData prop to do anything. So i created an Error component to live inside `layouts/error` file and then in the mounted hook i accessed the store as per usual

```
async mounted(){
   await this.$store.dispatch('getStuff')
}
```

This ended up fetching all the data (that i feel like should have been prefetched when doing `npm run generate`) and then my dynamic content worked.